# Can Form Header Tiles Be Re-sized in Microsoft Dynamics CRM

Tags: crm, dynamics-crm-2013

Whenever I try to change width of the header i doesn't makes any differences. When I changed the field formating to two columns then i got the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DOM manipulations are not supported inside Dynamics CRM.

Explain to your customer that this will cause issues when they need to upgrade/install rollups.

Answer (score 1):

Potentially, you can make more room using the existing fields, especially if one of those fields is a date field like the CreatedOn.  Rather than removing the field, you can edit the field properties for that CreatedOn field and change it so that the format of the field is "Date Only" instead of "Date and Time".  Note that this changes the display of that field everywhere it's used, not just in the header when making this change.

By doing that, it will still be supported, and will allow more room in the other header fields.